# GlassFish For vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, glassfish

I want to make a netbeans project into a vscode project, this project has Glassfish configured with it. I tried looking for glassfish extensions on vscode, but nothing showed.
`Is there a way to start my glassfish server with vscode?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [community server connector extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-community-server-connector) and from there configure your glassfish server. After that just make a war file of your project and deploy it!